# UseQuery + loop =?

Tags: react-hooks, react-apollo

How do I use `useQuery` in a loop. I know that it is not recommended per hook rules that hooks are not inside loops/ conditionals.

scenario:

```
const getSomething = (key) => {
  const [data] = useQuery(someQuery, {variables: key})
  return data;
}

const getInfo = () => {
  const keys = ["one", "two", "etc"];
  // ideally would like to loop over each key and get the data
  /* ideal code would be:
     return keys.map(key => getSomething(key));
  */
  // but since hooks can't be used in a loop, I have to end up writing like this:
  const data1 = getSomething(keys[0]);
  const data2 = getSomething(keys[1]);
  const data3 = getSomething(keys[2]);
  // data manipulation after... 

}
```

is there anyway to write this better instead of having to hard code for each key and data? And API has to be query with single key.

Comment: you can use Promise.all() https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/all

Comment: I could use Promise.all, but then that wouldn't support useQuery hook.